# Programa que no finaliza

Tags: java, optimización, condiciones, ciclos

estoy haciendo un programa, se pide que se entren 3 datos, si los 3 son incorrectos el programa finaliza, hago un bucle do / while y pide los 3 datos el problema es que el programa no finaliza y pasa analizar la siguiente condición, como hago para que finalice después de introducir 3 datos erróneos?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int edad = 0;
    int edad_max = 14;
    int edad_min = 7;
    int id;
    int id_max = 2000;
    int id_min = 1;
    int Intents = 3;
    int i = 0;
    int j=0;
    int intents_totals=0;

    boolean correcto = true;

    do {
        //llegim si es correcte
        System.out.println("digam ID:");
        correcto = scan.hasNextInt();
        if (correcto) {
            id = scan.nextInt();

            if ((id < 1) || (id > 1000)) {
                correcto = false;
                System.err.println("id incorecte, torni a introduirlo: ");
            }

        }

        //System.err.println("el numero te que ser sencer,torni a teclejarlo");
        i++;
    } while ((!correcto)&&(i < 3));
    // aqui deberia finalizar si los 3 intentos hemos introducido dato incorrecto
    // pero salta al siguiente do while

    do {
        i = 0;

        System.out.println("digam l´edad");

        correcto = scan.hasNextInt();
        if (correcto) {
            edad = scan.nextInt();

            if (edad < edad_min || edad > edad_max) {

                correcto = false;
                System.err.println("edad incorrecte, torni a introduirla");

            }
        }
        scan.nextLine();
        i++;
    } while (!correcto && i < Intents);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para finalizar tu programa, necesitas hacer un `return;` en alguna parte.

Una manera de integrar la modificación a tu programa es modificando la condición de la bucle un poco, y agregar otra condición adentro de la bucle para finalizar el programa si llevas demasiados intentos:

```
do {
    //llegim si es correcte
    System.out.println("digam ID:");
    correcto = scan.hasNextInt();
    if (correcto) {
        id = scan.nextInt();

        if ((id < 1) || (id > 1000)) {
            correcto = false;
            System.err.println("id incorecte, torni a introduirlo: ");
        }

    }

    i++;

    if (i >= 3) {
        return; // finaliza el programa después de 3 intentos.
    }
} while (!correcto);
```

**Edición**

Lo que los demás dicen en cuanto a inicializar `i` fuera de tu segundo bucle es correcto.  Pero eso es un problema distinto/adicional en tu programa que vas a tener que corregir.

**Edición 2**

Si no puedes usar `return;` o `break;`, puedes agregar una condición antes de tu segunda bucle así:

```
if (correcto) {
    i = 0;
    do {
        // ...
    } while (...);
}
```

Comment: No me dejan finalizar el bucle con soluciones como return o break de ahi mi problema

Comment: @Carlos: Otra opción es rodear la segunda bucle con un `if (correcto) { ... }`, para que solo se ejecute si tu primera bucle resultó bien. Con esa manera de hacerlo, no necesitas hacer un `return;`

Comment: Utilizando esta opcion me da cuatro intentos en vez de tres, despues de los cuatro intentos fallidos el bucle se rompe y salta error....

Answer (score 3):

Si deseas detener tu aplicación tienes que realizar una validación aquí:

```
   do {
        //llegim si es correcte
        System.out.println("digam ID:");
        correcto = scan.hasNextInt();
        if (correcto) {
            id = scan.nextInt();

            if ((id < 1) || (id > 1000)) {
                correcto = false;
                System.err.println("id incorecte, torni a introduirlo: ");
            }

        }

        //System.err.println("el numero te que ser sencer,torni a teclejarlo");
        i++;
    } while ((!correcto)&&(i < Intents));

//Termina el bucle y revisa si i >= Intents y en base a esto termina:

    if (!(i < Intents)){
     return;
    }
```

---

En el segundo bucle debes inicializar fuera de tu bucle la variable `i`, ya que el problema es que el valor de `i` siempre se esta inicializando con el valor de 0 y no se produce la condición para terminar el bucle:

```
 i = 0;
 do {
        //i = 0; //INCORRECTO!

        System.out.println("digam l´edad");

        correcto = scan.hasNextInt();
        if (correcto) {
            edad = scan.nextInt();

            if (edad < edad_min || edad > edad_max) {

                correcto = false;
                System.err.println("edad incorrecte, torni a introduirla");

            }
        }
        scan.nextLine();
        i++;
    } while (!correcto && i < Intents); //Si siempre inicializas i = 0 esto no se cumplira!.
```

Si siempre es inicializado `i = 0` la sentencia 
`i < Intents` siempre se cumplira y no se terminara el bucle ya que `i` siempre seria menor a `Intents`

Comment: Perdón por el edit. Lo hice a la vez que el tuyo. Editalo de nuevo con la nueva info.

Comment: No te preocupes amigo, de hecho es mejor poner bucle que loop, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ok entre do/while la i=0; fuera, pero el problema es que cuando paso el primer bucle do while si he ingresado 3 valores incorrectos el programa deberia parar, pero este sigue ejeutandose al siguiente do/while, ese es mi problema...

Comment: ok agregue una actualización, simplemente revisa si al terminar i es mayor o igual a Intents, que tiene un valor de 3. Recuerda que la segunda corrección tambien la tienes que realizar que es sacar la asignación i = 0 fuera del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

El último `do/while` se evalua siempre poniendo `i=1`. Deberías de sacar la línea `i=0` antes empezar con el `do/while`.

Comment: Hecho gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Tu lógica dentro del while esta mal, ya que pides que ambas condiciones se cumplan y lo que necesitas es que solo alguna de ellas se cumpla es decir mientras !correcto o i<3. Ten cuidado con tu variable "correcto", ya que si ingresas por teclado algun valor que no sea boolean te marcará un error.

Comment: He probado de cambiarlo como dices pero me salta un error...

Comment: podrías poner el error?

Comment: Mira cambio asi } while ((!correcto)||(i < 3)); y entonces cuando introduzco el dato, perdon no es error, simplemente no sale nunca del bucle, por ejemplo marco id= 0 como correcto 0 false , se queda siempre ahi, pasa del 3 intento  y no evalua la sgunda parte i<3

Comment: para que quieres validar "correcto" y porque lo obtienes del teclado?